# Django Uploading xls files

Tags: python, django, excel, file-upload

I am new to django and I want to make a simple task though I am a bit confused with the django framework.

I want to allow the user upload an xls file, then I want to run my own python script on this xls file (like extracting words for example), and then show an informative message to the user.

Where can I start? I red the django tutorial and I looked at some answeres here that are related but still I don't know how to begin.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Can you please share the snippet of your code?

Comment: http://thepythondjango.com/upload-process-excel-file-django/

Answer (score 2):

There is a chapter about this in the [django docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/) - just the first paragraph "Basic File Upload". xls files are not any special to django and are handled the same way as all other files.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tutorials I had hanged before so I can recommend;

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_file_uploading.htm

http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I hope it helps